# How to insert parameters from a MySQL query? User name and Password ...Query Parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, mysql-workbench, visual-c++-2012

I need to enter a couple of user names and their passwords in SQL database... 
How to prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
Rather than change the code stayed in the original decision, hoping that my database will be well protected but I splintered it in every case.

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand ("select * from data.eid where User_Name = (?usr) and Password = (?pwd);", conDataBase);
cmdDataBase->Parameters.Add("?usr", this -> username_txt );
cmdDataBase->Parameters.Add("?pwd", this -> password_txt );
cmdDataBase->Prepare();
cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
```

then with another user:

```
cmdDataBase->Parameters[0].value = <username>;
cmdDataBase->Parameters[1].value = <password>;
cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
```

EDIT:

I'm ignoring retrieving results in this example.

Comment: cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add and cmdDataBase.Prepare(); I can't use this statements....

Comment: @Stanojkovic why is that?

Comment: I have not seen a single post (I was browsing through many websites) that would give the correct code for C + + CLI and Visual C + + to prevent SQL injection. 
There are several explanations and tutorials for C # and VB. 
Is there a language translator that translates code from C # and VB to VC + +, or whether there is a possibility to implement part of the project, which is written in C # and VB in VC + + projects?
My eyes are burnt and my brain was fried from countless attempts to solve this mystery on my own. :)

Comment: @Stanojkovic perhaps because you're not asking the right questions. For starters, you're not saying which connector you're using. I'm **assuming** it's Connector/NET. Now you're saying it's Visual C++, but your code **does not look** C++ at all. So make up your mind and state clearly what you want - platform, connector, etc. Moreover, when you say something linke `I can't use this statemets` what should I get from that?? How about telling me what the problem is (error messages, etc.). And C++ and C++ CLI are diffent things, so don't confuse those...

Comment: I get error messages like "cmdDataBase is undefined" and "expected an expression" for this cmdDataBase.Parameters[0].value = <username>;

Comment: @Stanojkovic errors like `cmdDataBase is undefined` is kind of self explanatory, isn't it? The example I gave you is by no means complete. You have to declare `cmdDataBase` first. I've altered my example, which also contained a mistake, as cmdDataBase is a pointer, not reference.